# Check whether IIS is installed or not

Tags: powershell, iis, service, wmi

I am writing a PowerShell script to host a website in IIS.

I tried this script in a machine where there is no IIS installed and I got error so I want to check if IIS is installed and then I want to host a website in ISS.

Below is the script I am trying but it is not working:

```
$vm = "localhost";
$iis = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $vm -Filter "name='IISADMIN'"

if ($iis.State -eq "Running") {
    Write-Host "IIS is running on $vm"
} 
else {
    Write-Host "IIS is not running on $vm"
}
```

Please help me with any PowerShell script to check if IIS is installed or not.

Comment: Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server...check install state property

Answer (score 12):

```
if ((Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server).InstallState -eq "Installed") {
    Write-Host "IIS is installed on $vm"
} 
else {
    Write-Host "IIS is not installed on $vm"
}
```

Comment: **Get-WindowsFeature** is sometimes not present in Windows 10 pcs. 
I think Get-WindowsOptionalFeature might be the way to go.

Comment: @Anthony You might need to run `Import-Module servermanager` to enable it. On Windows VMs(Windows Server e.g.) Server Manager is installed by default, so `Get-WindowsFeature` is available here. But on other Windows 10 pcs thats not the case.

Answer (score 3):

In an elevated Powershell window this works for me:

On `Windows Server 2012` (on `Windows Server 2008` first run this: `Import-Module ServerManager`)

```
if ((Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server).Installed) {
    Write-Host "IIS installed"
}
```

On `Windows 10`

```
if ((Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-WebServerRole").State -eq "Enabled") {
    Write-Host "IIS installed"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this for a list of several hundred servers today.  I modified the previous answer to use get-service w3svc instead of WMI installed state.  This seems to be working for me so far.

```
$servers = get-content  c:\listofservers.txt
foreach($server in $servers){
$service = get-service -ComputerName $server w3svc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($service)
{
Write-Host "IIS installed on $server"
} 
else {
Write-Host "IIS is not installed on $server"
}}
```