# PowerShell - Check whether IIS is installed or not

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that determines if IIS is installed or not on Windows 10. If it is not installed I would like to offer the user to install it and have the installation be done though PowerShell.

I saw the post here: [Check whether IIS is installed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673926/check-whether-iis-is-installed-or-not)

But when running `Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server` I'm getting `not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`. So I tried running `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature Web-Server` but that returns `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Web-Server'.`

How can I check if IIS is installed? And how can I install it?

Comment: One default way of checking is if `Get-Service W3SVC` returns a non-error.

Comment: This may be unrelated but I'm very curious why you're installing IIS on Windows 10 anyway? Running a web server on a client is usually pretty frowned upon and may greatly increase your attack surface.

Comment: @n3tl0kr It's a script for automating the setting up of a web-developer environment.

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but seems feasible. You will of course have to decide which features you actually want to install.

```
$IIS = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName “IIS-WebServer”
if ($IIS.State -eq "Disabled") { 
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName $IIS.FeatureName -Online
}
```

You can use `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online` to determine what is enabled or not by looking at the `State` property of the results.

Comment: `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Web-Server'.`

Comment: Then just put quotes around the value